# Why the e.preventDefault is cancelling all the other lines of code after itself?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server

When I put the e.preventdefault() after the code it works, however it refreshes the page.

If I leave it at the beginning of the code, it prevent the other lines to run and don't pull the request.

```js
  function loadPhoto(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //forming images
    var formData  = new FormData( document.getElementById("uploading") );
    for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("up").files.length; i++) {
      console.log(i)
      formData.append("up[]",document.getElementById("up").files[i]);
    }


    var filename = document.getElementById('up');
    alert(filename)
    filename = filename.files[0].name;
    alert(filename)

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/reqUpload');
    xhr.onload = function(){
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        alert(this.responseText)
             document.getElementById('#photo').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
    xhr.send(formData);
  }
```

Comment: My guess: Your code crashes with `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault')` because `e` is undefined, but you don't see that because you didn't look into your devtools console. And the reason it crashes in the first place could be because you used `onclick="loadPhoto()"` instead of `onclick="loadPhoto(event)"` (or maybe `onsubmit`). If you put it at the end it doesn't "work" either, because it just crashes at the end then, which is why you see the page refreshed (which is actually the form being submitted normally since it did _not_ prevent the default action).

Comment: To help more, we'd need to know the error you get in your console and the code that calls or references `loadPhoto`.

Comment: I had a look at the devtools. Didn't show any errors, but I think you are right, maybe is the way I am calling the function.
<input type="submit" id="upBtn" class="upBtn" value="upload photo and submit" onclick=" loadPhoto()"/>
Will try to listen to the even click and see if works

Comment: Make sure "Preserve log" is enabled in the console so you can see the error even after the page refreshed, and make sure devtools are open while you click the button. Based on what you just said, it's exactly what I thought and changing it to `onclick="loadPhoto(event)"` should fix it. In the `onXXX` handler string, you can use `event` to access the current event object, so you can pass it to your function this way. Without that, nothing is ever filled into `e`!

Comment: Champs, you're right! Thank you
onclick="loadPhoto(event) -> this worked well.

However, now the image does not display on the #photo.
<img id="photo" class="photo">

Comment: An `<img>` tag cannot have children. Maybe you meant `src` instead of `innerHTML`? (assuming the response text is just the URL)

Comment: Nah, not working any way.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it by using `onclick="loadPhoto(event)"`